# I love what I am, do you?

Tags: riddle

Simple riddle, but figured I'd throw it out.

> I have an idea inside me
>   But it'll never come to be
>   The idea is (usually) protected, but is it for me or for you?
>   A simple flick of your wrist
>   And I might just die
>   But another flick can bring me back to life
>   I'll help you to see in your darkest hour
>   But when it's too bright, I lose effective power
>   Oh, how I long to be free!
>   But I am tethered with a leash
>   Still, I love me for what I am
>   Do you?

Accepted answer will explain all parts of the riddle!

**Hint**

> I got twisted around and saw a shady news report.

**Explanation for "I love me for what I am"**

> Replacing "me" with the answer, "lamp", and you get "I love lamp.", a well-known line from the movie "Anchorman", which is where the "news report" from the Hint comes into play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought for sure it's...

> ...a light bulb...

...but now I see that's just one piece of the puzzle and it's really...

> ...a lamp

```
I have an idea inside me
But it'll never come to be
```

> A lamp contains a light bulb.  Having an idea is often referred to as "a light bulb going off", and is depicted as a light bulb over one's head.

```
The idea is (usually) protected, but is it for me or for you?
```

> A lamp shade surrounds the light bulb.  Is it keeping the light in or keeping you out?

```
A simple flick of your wrist
And I might just die
But another flick can bring me back to life
```

> Turning/pushing the switch turns the lamp on and off.

```
I'll help you to see in your darkest hour
But when it's too bright, I lose effective power
```

> Lamps illuminate the darkness, but when there's too much ambient light (day time), the light from the lamp is less effective.

```
Oh, how I long to be free!
But I am tethered with a leash
```

> The lamp is tethered to the wall by the power cord.

```
Still, I love me for what I am
Do you?
```

> I don't know what this means.  Something to do with the spelling of L-A-M-P?  Lowercase 'L' looks like an uppercase 'I' creating "I AM...P"?  Or is it just that "I am" (sort of) rhymes with "lamp"?

```
I got twisted around and saw a shady news report.
```

> Is the lamp on a table with a newspaper, and after being rotated only part of the newspaper is in light and part is in shade?  Or is it an old/antique lamp that's been boxed up and wrapped in newspaper for storage?  That might explain asking "Do you love me?" (it's an old, forgotten object but still could be useful), though it'd no longer be plugged in at that point.

Comment: You have the right answer... All except for I love me. Take a look at the last few words of the hint... I'll accept it when I get home, but hopefully you'll have the correct explanation!

Comment: The hint doesn't need explanation. It was just alluding to twisting to turn a light on, and shady was alluding to lamp shade. Now for the news report part... Figure that out! Think about that and the phrasing... I love me...

Answer (score 4):

Let's give it a try:

I have an idea inside me

> A watch talks about the idea of counting the time before the world ends.

But it'll never come to be

> But the end will probably never come, so it is "doomed" to count forever and the idea will never achieve its final aim.

The idea is (usually) protected, but is it for me or for you?

> This sentence is hard to explain, does it talk about the physical protection the watches have to be durable? Or is it about the fact that time-tracking is so advanced today (we can even count microseconds) that it is impossible to make a mistake? One way or another, is this protection meant to be for the watch (to give meaning for its existence) or is it meant to exist for us, to be able to schedule things, count ageing etc.?

A simple flick of your wrist

And I might just die

> You check the time, you then turn your wrist and although the watch is still there and you carry it, it just counts uselessly. No one pays attention to it, it is like it's dead.

But another flick can bring me back to life

> But then you literally *flick your wrist* to check again your watch and this adds meaning to its existence, it "resurrects" it.

I'll help you to see in your darkest hour

> Play with the words, as the new watches have light to show you the time when it is dark. Also, when at night, we lose track of time, because there is no sun...

But when it's too bright, I lose effective power

> ... but during the day, you can approximately tell the time by looking at the sky and the sun's position. It is also more difficult to use the watch (?).

Still, I love me for what I am
Do you?

> The watch loves itself as it serves such an important purpose and is indispensable, even with the smartphones taking over, but do we? Do we enjoy our lives as time goes by, does the time-tracking makes us more anxious, does it even have a meaning any more to count the time?

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but wow, I'm impressed with your explanations.

Comment: Yes I guessed so since you said to Yllrauei that he is on the right track. But I thought I should give it a try nevertheless!

Comment: Such a deep answer, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> Light bulb?

Because

> 'I have an idea inside me' 
>  'But it'll never come to be'
>  'The idea is protected, but is it for me or is it for you?'
>  'A simple flick of your wrist' Turning a switch on
>  'And I might just die'
>  'But another flick can bring me back to life' Turning a switch off
>  'I'll help you to see in your darkest hour' Lightbulbs help you see 
>  'But when it's too bright I lose effective power' When it's bright out, lightbulbs don't do much
>  'Still, I love me for what I am'
>  'Do you?'
>
>
> Although, I'm still not sure about the idea part. It might be about the representation of an idea using a lightbulb

Comment: Take a look at each line and find an answer that will fit each one.

Comment: You're on the right track, but the answer will be associated with every line of the riddle (or pair of lines where appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> Torch

7. > Torch has a leash at the end to usually put it around then hand

6.

> Torches are of no use if it's  too bright.

5. > Torch  give us light when there is no power.

4.

> We can turn the torch on and off by pushing / pulling the button on top of the torch basically simple flick of the wrist

I came up with the above relations , still thinking about other pieces

Comment: Still doesn't account for all lines! On the right track, though! Keep going with these thought processes!

Comment: @Josh updated my answer but an incomplete one

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea inside me
But it'll never come to be

> A dream

The idea is (usually) protected, but is it for me or for you?

> The idea is safely protected as we are asleep and subjectivity is surely beyond question in sleep.

A simple flick of your wrist
And I might just die
But another flick can bring me back to life

> If the flick causes a sprain or a crack surely the dream dies.

I'll help you to see in your darkest hour
But when it's too bright, I lose effective power

> Of course we dream on the darkest hour of the night as we tend to sleep in states of dream and beyond in that hour.

Still, I love me for what I am
Do you?

> Absolutely love dreaming as long as it's not a nightmare!

Comment: Interesting take on the riddle. Not the correct answer, but I like how you think outside the box.

Comment: Thanks for that, is it a switch or an electricity!!!

Comment: Neither. Take a look at a couple of the other answers. They are on the right track, just not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not right but I'd thought I'll try. Are you a?

> Smart Watch?

I have an idea inside me:

> Code, Routines, Programs, etc. (maybe this also includes AI?)

But it'll never come to be

> On most smartwatches, the innermost workings/code are restricted/encrypted so you can't access it

The idea is (usually) protected, but is it for me or for you?

> Same as above, but you can usually see the result of the hidden code through a GUI

A simple flick of your wrist. 
And I might just die

> Flick your wrist away and it'll die/ turn off

But another flick can bring me back to life

> Flick it back and it'll turn on

I'll help you to see in your darkest hour

> Shine the display as a flashlight

But when it's too bright, I lose effective power

> Too much brightness can significantly reduce battery life. Might have to do with "effective power" bug on iPhone

Still, I love me for what I am

> Smartwatches and their built-in AI (Siri, Google now), usually say positive things about themselves

Do you?

> Some people like smart watches, others don't

Comment: Good thought process indeed. Still not what I'm looking for, but I like how you think!